# React-three-fiber drei - lookat not being set for perspective camera with fly controls

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I am using fly controls with drei. I can't seem to set the lookat position for the camera. Here is the controls and camera.

```
<FlyControls ref={flyRef}
           enableDamping={false}
           movementSpeed={3}
           rollSpeed={0.05}
           dragToLook={true}
           makeDefault={cameraView==0} /> }


<PerspectiveCamera ref={pcRef}
                 position={new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1)}
                 heightMin={2}
                 heightMax={2}
                 fov={45}
                 makeDefault={cameraView==0}
                 up={new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1)} />
```

I tried using the following as part of a useEffect hook:

```
flyRef.current.target = lookat; 
flyRef.current.update();
```

However, this does not alter the lookat position. I tried placing a lookat property on the initial perspective camera, but this does not do anything either.

Comment: did you end up finding a solution to this? I'm having the same issue